# value of type java.lang..String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

these are my codes for make a Json in android and i have an exception when i run the programm!! plz help me

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
   Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     try {


         AssetManager manager = getResources().getAssets();
         InputStream Is= manager.open("myjson.json");
         String result="";
         int c = 0;
         while ((Is.read())!=-1){

             result +=(char)c;

         }
         Is.close();

         JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
         final JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);


         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                  try {


                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id is:" + object.getString("Day"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name is:" + object.getString("Start"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type is:" + object.getString("Finish"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                  }catch (Exception e){
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                  }

         });


     }catch (Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

}
```

}

and these are the Json codes:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 5207,
        "Name": "Эриван",
        "Types": [
            "Ресторан"
        ],
        "Latitude": 53.904752,
        "Longitude": 27.521095,
        "OperatingTime": [
            {
                "Day": 1,
                "Start": "10:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Day": 2,
                "Start": "10:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Day": 3,
                "Start": "10:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Day": 4,
                "Start": "10:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Day": 5,
                "Start": "10:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Day": 6,
                "Start": "08:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            },
            {
                "Day": 0,
                "Start": "08:00:00",
                "Finish": "23:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "IsBookingAvailable": false
    }]
```

Comment: It would probably help if you were to add the exception stack trace to the question. Also, since we can't really tell line numbers from code snippets, point out the relevant line.

Comment: i changed the Toasts but it did not answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id is:" + object.getString("Day"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name is:" + object.getString("Start"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type is:" + object.getString("Finish"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
// object.getString("Id")
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id is:" + object.getString("Id"),
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// object.getString("Name")
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name is:" + object.getString("Name"), 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// object.getJSONArray("Types").toString()
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "type is:" + 
        object.getJSONArray("Types").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**"Day"**, **"Start"** & **"Finish"** are not accessible directly via `object`. They are located within several nested `JSONObject`s of the **"OperatingTime"** `JSONArray`.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is Java naming convention.

Comment: @Stanojkovic I'm not sure that I understand what you've just said.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG I don't think he realized that you changed the objects being retrieved from the JSON

Comment: @davehenry seems like it

Comment: i can't resolve my problem!!! the exception is for the first try,catch!! these codes have a problem!!                                                                                    
         AssetManager manager = getResources().getAssets();
         InputStream Is= manager.open("myjson.json");
         String result="";
         int c = 0;
         while ((Is.read())!=-1){

             result +=(char)c;

         }
         Is.close();

         JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
         final JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);